# Logical indexing in JAVA

Tags: java, matlab, matrix, indexing

How to do access array elements using logical indexing in Java?

Matlab/Octave equivalent of what I want to do:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
logicalarray=[0 1 0 0 0 1];
result= A(logical)
```

which gives `result =[2 6]`

If I have the same `A` and `logicalarray` in Java. How would I get that `result` without using loops?

Comment: you don't, you have to loop - either manual or implicitly by using a stream and filter.

Comment: @luk2302 which one of them should be preferred in terms of performance or are they all the same? We usually prefer to avoid loops in Octave for better performance. can you please post an answer of doing that with different approaches? i am new to java

Comment: Java has completely different syntax, you can't do what you can do in matlab. Unless you want to call matlab code from java https://github.com/diffplug/matconsolectl

Comment: Does the logical array only contain 0s and 1s and indicates `false` and `true` by that? Then I would try using some `Map<Integer,Boolean>` with the number (from A) as the key and a boolean value to indicate if the number is to be packed into the result array or set.

Comment: @deHaar  Thanks for the reply. yes that array contains only 0s and 1s. will  you please post an answer?

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the suggestion. Although doing that would be very convenient for me but i was hoping to learn java

Comment: I suggest that you forget everything you know about Matlab and just learn java from scratch. It has no built in support for matrices operations like logical mask. After you do that you can look into scientific computing libraries like http://nd4j.org/ and http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/index.html that try to offer similar capabilities. *P.S.* You can only accept one answer so choose the one you like most and accept it. You can upvote as many as you like but your upvotes won't count until you will have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by [@Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398418/oleg) you have a complete different syntax in Java and as [@luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) mention you might use [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)

Following snippet

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// logicalarray=[0 1 0 0 0 1];
// index is zero-based in Java
int[] result = IntStream.of(1, 5)
        .map(i -> a[i])
        .toArray();

System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

would print

```
result = [2, 6]
```

**edit** If you need to keep the `logicalarray` a possible solution could be

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] logicalarray = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, logicalarray.length) // create a stream of array indexes
        .filter(i -> logicalarray[i] == 1) // filter the indexes which are 1 in logicalarray
        .map(i -> a[i]) // map the related value from array a
        .toArray(); // create an array of the values
System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: sorry they don't let me tick both answers

Comment: @Ekaba they dont let me upvote. they record my vote as feedback. I have tried

Comment: How did you reference me and luk? Did you just copy the link and added it with \[@username\](copiedLink) or is there an easier way?

Comment: @Oleg I copied the link. I'm not aware of an other way inside an answer. Even in comments you have the auto-magic only for a single name.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int[] L = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        int[] n = IntStream.range(0, A.length).map(i -> A[i] * L[i]).filter(i->i>0).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much